# Drag and drop in WPF ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, drag-and-drop

I'm using WPF ListView, where SelectionMode is set to Extended (you can select multiple items only with ctrl pressed). I need to implement D&D between two ListViews. To perform drag event, I used DragItem event in WinForms, but such an event is not provided in wpf. I've decided to use ListViewItem PreviewMouseDownClick

```
private void ListViewItemMouseDownClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.AllowDragDrop)
    {
        return;
    }

    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(
        ListViewItemsCollection, this.SelectedItems, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
}
```

Unfortunately such a solution has a bug: selecting single item (without ctrl pressed) works. However, I need to double-click to select item while ctrl is pressed in order to select multiple items. There is no difference when using ListView's PreviewMouseDown or ListViewItem's PreviewMouseDown. Any ideas how to solve problem?

Comment: [Gong Drag and Drop Framework for WPF which supports MVVM](http://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/)

Comment: See this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929474/drag-multiple-items-from-wpf-listview

Comment: Gong Drag and Drop is not working - installed from NuGet. (I don't remember exactly what was wrong, but app couldn't load assemlby). I'll try the second solution. It looks like a hack (I hope there elegant solution) but if it is working.. it is worth a try.

Comment: Unfortunately implementation that use MouseMove is not working with Extended SelectionMode. When multiple items are selected and I drag them via one of them, only the one them stay selected .

Comment: Need to get the latest GongSolutions.WPF.DragDrop library from https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop, I just compiled and the demo works fine.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found solution, works like a chram:
[social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/e57349f1-418c-4f94-a933-8e574121ffcc/).
I joined it with code from moncadad's link. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the answer here instead of only providing a link.