# WPF Datagrid multiple selection is lost on drag

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drag multiple selected rows from one DataGrid to another. For this I am using a handler for the `MouseMove` event like this:

```
    private void Distribution_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            var dg = sender as DataGrid;
            if (dg == null) return;
            if (dg.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;

            Point p = e.GetPosition(this);
            HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, p);
            var obj = result.VisualHit;

            while (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj) != null && !(obj is DataGridRow))
            {
                obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
            }
            if (obj == null) return;

            var row = obj as DataGridRow;
            if (row == null) return;

            if (dg.SelectedItems.Contains(row.DataContext))
            {
                e.Handled = true;

                DataObject data = new DataObject();
                data.SetData("registries", dg.SelectedItems.Cast<Registry>().ToList());
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, having multiple rows selected, clicking to drag and drop makes the clicked row become the only selected row and only that row gets moved.

How can I keep the multiple selection or what other event should I use to start dragging before the selection is changed?

Comment: What about `PreviewMouseMove` event, you should try that instead of `MouseMove`.

Comment: @KingKing using `PreviewMouseMove` shows the same problem. I was trying to do it in `[Preview]MouseLeftButtonDown` but I can not get it to work without breaking the normal selection behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19713205/3557327).

First I added a PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown handler that would add all the selected items to another list:

```
    private List<Registro> _selected = new List<Registry>();
    private void Distribution_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var dg = sender as DataGrid;
        if (dg == null) return;
        _selected.Clear();
        _selected.AddRange(dg.SelectedItems.Cast<Registry>());
    }
```

And then on the MouseMove handler added the following after `e.Handled = true;` and before creating the DataObject:

```
                foreach (var registry in _selected)
                {
                    if (!dg.SelectedItems.Contains(registry))
                    {
                        dg.SelectedItems.Add(registry);
                    }
                }
```

It shows visibly the elements being deselected and selected again in the grid, but it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for this function, I have one addition: you only want the _selected list to be filled when the row the user clicked on is selected. Otherwise, the old selection will be dragged even if you selected another item and immediately start dragging it. Therefore, you can use 
 var row = FindVisualParent<DataGridRow>(e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement);
            if (row != null && row.IsSelected)
                        _selected.AddRange(dg.SelectedItems.Cast<Registry>());